# changing tailwind.config.js in a laravel 10 project does not seem to be recognized

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I have a new laravel 10 project using tailwindcss.
I am making changes to tailwind.config.js located in the root of the project.

After i make a change to this file, do i need to do anything else to incorporate the changes?

this is my config file

```
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import forms from '@tailwindcss/forms';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    darkMode: 'class',
    content: [
    './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
],

theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        },
    },
},
variants: {
    extend: {
        display: ['dark']
    },
},
plugins: [
    forms,
    require('flowbite/plugin')
],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing your tailwind.config.js file, you need to rebuild your CSS. This is because Tailwind CSS generates its utility classes at build time. So, any changes you make in the configuration file will not take effect until you rebuild your CSS.

```
npm run build
```